# How do set table widths work when inserting a wider detail?

Tags: html

If you set a detail width, `<td width="10"...>`, what happens to the detail if you put something wider, such as a picture that is 20 pixels wide, in that detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

td elements will expand to match their contents by default.

If you use css, you can set max-width and oveflow:hidden and the element will not expand.

```
td{
    max-width:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/613kpweh/2/